# Django many-to-many, display in admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, many-to-many

Please help to understand how to display list of groups in Django admin **Person** instance in this case:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield(max_length=120)

class Group(models.Model):
  title = models.Charfield(max_length=120)
  persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [`inlines`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines). Add this to the `admin.py` file:

```
from .models import Group

class GroupInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Group.persons.through
    extra = 1

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [GroupInline]

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

See details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).

Comment: This was not quite enough for me. I had to add `fk_name = 'from_person'` to remove the ambiguity between the forward and the backward relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You can inline **"Group"** to **"Person"** with this code below:

**admin.py"**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Group, Person

class GroupInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Group

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [GroupInline]
```